# BS Header with right aligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add to my header on the right an additional small element that is aligned to to right as follwed:

```
<h1>Header<small>subheader<span class="pull-right">subheader right</span></small></h1>
```

However the span element on the right is placed higher/ not in line with the first small element. What am I doing wrong?

I do not want to use the css grid.

Comment: You'll need to show us a working example of the problem. But generally the first question on things like this is "Have you tried vertical-align"?

Comment: style="vertical-align:bottom" does not work

Comment: the example I use is above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do.

```
h1{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}
small{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
span{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

You can remove pull right class from span.

Comment: thank you! that works for me. I set the align-items to baseline though